# Docker shiny server goes to sample welcome page automatically

Tags: r, docker, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have successfully run Clustvis container (https://github.com/taunometsalu/ClustVis) on windows before. It works well. Today I removed the container and run the exact same command line as before. Then I open the address in browser, some how it shows the shiny sample "welcome" page. Please help.

Here is the command I run:

```
docker run -d --name customClustvisColor -p 7777:3838 -v C:\Users\myname\Documents\customClustvisColor\customClustvis\ClustVis-master\:\srv\shiny-server\:ro taunometsalu/clustvis
```

Now http://localhost:7777/ shows a sample page
[image]

Again, it worked perfectly last time. But somehow not working now...

Answer (score 0):

With the help from the author of ClustVis taunometsalu, I re-run the container with "/" replacing all "\". Now it's working fine. The backward slash worked before, maybe the new docker update no longer accept it.